# Rails Formtastic nested form - form for attributes from join model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, formtastic, nested-attributes

The problem I am facing with `Formtastic` is that I have a Form to create a new `Order`. In this form I want to select multiple existing `Food` items from a list. These should be added to the new Order I am submitting. At the same time I also want to set attributes in the `FoodOrder` join model. This Model has an integer quantity attribute for which i would like to have a field in my form.

What I am basically looking for is a form that lists all Food Items and puts a field for the `quantity` on the same line as the Food Item it belongs to.

The Models

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :food_orders
  has_many :foods, :through => :food_orders
end

class FoodOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :order
end

class Food < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :food_orders
  has_many :orders, :through => :food_orders
  belongs_to :category
end
```

This is one of the versions of the form I have tried so far. But I am just baffled and do not know how to get fields for the FoodOrder Model.

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@restaurant, @order] do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :comment %><br />
    <%= f.input :table_id %><br />
    <%# <%= f.input :foods, :as => :check_boxes %>
    <%= f.inputs :for => :foods do |food| %>
      <%= food %>
      <%= food.inputs :quantity %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My models have these attributes

```
create_table "food_orders", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "quantity",   :null => false
  t.decimal  "price",      :null => false
  t.integer  "food_id",    :null => false
  t.integer  "order_id",   :null => false
  t.text     "comment"
  t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
end

create_table "foods", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "category_id",                     :null => false
  t.string   "name",                            :null => false
  t.string   "description"
  t.string   "image"
  t.decimal  "default_price",                   :null => false
  t.boolean  "active",        :default => true, :null => false
  t.datetime "created_at",                      :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                      :null => false
end

create_table "orders", :force => true do |t|
  t.integer  "restaurant_id",                    :null => false
  t.integer  "user_id",                          :null => false
  t.integer  "table_id",                         :null => false
  t.decimal  "total",                            :null => false
  t.datetime "finished_at"
  t.datetime "created_at",                       :null => false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                       :null => false
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what I would end up doing is creating a `FoodOrder` object for each `Food` then only save the ones that have a value above 0.

You could do that in a `reject_if` for the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` but that wouldn't deleted the old `FoodOrder`s that someone might change from 3 to 0. So instead you will have to override the `quantity=` method for `FoodOrder`.

I've never used `formtastic` before but I'm going to take a guess and say that this should work.

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@restaurant, @order] do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :comment %><br />
    <%= f.input :table_id %><br />
    <% @foods.each do |food|
      <%= f.semantic_fields_for :food_orders, 
                            @order.food_orders.detect_or_build_by_food(food)
                            do |food_order| %>
        <%= food %>
        <%= food_order.inputs :quantity %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.buttons do %>
    <%= f.commit_button %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

order.rb:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :restaurant
  has_many :foods, :through => :food_orders
  has_many :food_orders do
    def detect_or_build_by_food(food)
      record = self.detect{ |food_order| food_order.food_id == food.id }
      if record.nil?
        record = self.build(:food => food)
      end
      record
    end
  end

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :food_orders
end
```

food_order.rb:

```
class FoodOrder < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :food
  belongs_to :order

  def quantity=(quantity)
    if quantity <= 0
      self.destroy
    else
      self[:quantity] = quantity
    end
  end
end
```

I would hope that works but it is untested code, so yeah... Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! The Form looks nice now, just like what I was looking for. Unfortunately I get a `can't modify frozen hash` Rails Runtime Error. Is it possible that modifying the quantity in `FoodOrder` is not allowed? Any idea where else that Error might be coming from?

Comment: Hmm, its probably the destroy in the method I'm going to be on my phone for the rest of the day, but you might try "mark_for_destruction" instead. But if that doesn't work take out the destroy completely and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Neither `.mark_for_destruction` nor commenting it out work. both lead to `SQLite3::ConstraintException: constraint failed: INSERT INTO "food_orders"`

Comment: You probably need a hidden field with "food_id". That error usually means that the database isn't getting a value it requires

Comment: I added a hidden field for the `food_id` but i still get the same Statement invalid. quite strange. {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"PxvWreNiO3ApTojDS5AmyusMnM1A8NNHPSsec4Pghhw=",
 "order"=>{"table_id"=>"1",
 "food_orders_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"quantity"=>"1",
 "comment"=>"hey",
 "food_id"=>"1"},
 "1"=>{"quantity"=>"",
 "comment"=>"",
 "food_id"=>"2"}
 },
 "commit"=>"Create Order",
 "restaurant_id"=>"1"}

Comment: ok i think i got it now. the only thing that doesnt't work is the overwritten attribute setter `def quantity=(quantity)` and `def price=(price)`. Neither one seems to set the attributes even if I do something trivial as `self[:price] = 1.1`